# Delete SQL rows with specific values from excel file list

Tags: sql, excel

I want to make an SQL query. I want to delete all the rows that include a specific email address. The string with the email addresses will load from an excel file. Instead of having to write the emails one by one like shown below:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE email ('aaa@aaa.com', 'bbb@bbb.com')
```

I would like to load the string using the excel file (.xlsx, .csv or any other filetype) where the email addresses are written.

```
LOAD * FROM excelfile.xlsx
```

or even load cell values from a specific column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this operation once, you can write a query in EXCEL, multiply it to all your lines and then copy-paste and execute your query.

Write EXCEL formula in the free row:

```
="DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE email  = '"&RC[-1]&"'"
```

[image: query from excel]

Drag it to all your data, and you will get SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE email  = 'aaa@aaa.com' 
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE email  = 'bbb@bbb.com'
```

Then copy/paste and execute your query

Comment: Your answer is good and helpful. But I would like to know a solution just in case. So, I want to learn how I can "call ", import the excel file in the query and specifically some excel cell values.